# Why free AWS EC2 server t2.micro instance of 750 hours exceed 85% in less than month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I started to use AWS EC2 server t2.micro instance with 750 hours for 12 months on 21.02.2019 and on 14.03.2019 I received this mail:

[image]

---

From 21.02.2019 I started just one instance and keep it running without interruption to this day. That is something around 500 hours, not 654. Even my account on AWS portal after login shows about instance this:

[image]

---

Could you please advise me what to do next, why it happens? All about this topic is written [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html). But it does not clarify my problem. I saw some similar questions through multiple domains but they told that problem is that someone run multiple instances, not just one... but I can clearly see that I have just one that I still not stopped or interrupted... I do not use any AWS database, but Google Cloud PSQL DB that is close to Frankfurt, where my AWS server is located...

Maybe this will be helpful:

[image]

---

One interesting sentence is this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html): "Some of the most common limits are by time, such as hourly or by the minute, or by requests, which are the requests you send to the service, also known as API operations." I do not understand it, maybe stupid question - sorry, but the more GET / POST request on my web occur, the quicker time goes? OR the more terminal SSL session instances I have the more time it consumes?

What's more, I connect with terminal to server 2 times a day for an 4 hours and I have 0 visitors on my web page. I use 2 ports, one for production(where I have runnig permanently thread with my site with nohup & and screen commands) and one for development simultaneously.

I wrote to AWS support, but as far as it is free account for now, the severity is LOW and therefore no respond. I have 3 days left I think and then I have to pay...don't understand why and why they did not reset calculation of hours with first day of March?

---

Other evidence:

[image]

---

And solution found thanks to answer here, 2 instances running, Frankfurt and Ohio:

[image]

---

But after shutting down an Ohio instance, another was created and started without my permission again:

[image]

---

In order to terminate instance permanently, disable auto scaling:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **only** possible cause of this would be that you actually have two, not one, instance running.  Check EC2 in all the other regions in the console, to find the other instance.

Time *does* reset on the first of the month, and this line item is not usage sensitive -- as little or as much traffic as you want does not change how machine hours are calculated.  API requests do not change how machine hours are calculated.  Formerly, stop/start events (similar to power off/power on, excluding simple reboot) on an instance would inflate the hours by 1 hour for each event but this has not been the case for a couple of years.

654÷2÷24 = 13.625 days of two separate instances running since the first of the month.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I have 2 instances running, Frankfurt and Ohio, but ... I see this is some kind of trick of Aamazon company?, because I am absolutely sure that I started just one instance at Frankfurt, I did it very patiently and in details ... why they started yet another instance without my permission at Ohio? In order to take advantage that I am new and to make me pay? Otherwise I do not understand how could this happen... see my updated question... I stopped ohio instance and without my permission = new was created

Comment: Amazon has never been known to play games like this. Maintain your dialog with support and assume that AWS is not trying to weasel you out of a few dollars.  I expect that they will help you avoid unexpected charges like this.  It's pretty common for new users to get disoriented by the way all the regions are independent. If they were trying to pack your bill with extra charges, they would not send you emails intended to help avoid exactly those charges.

Comment: For the new issue: The `-env` on the instance name and the automatic respawn suggest that this is an instance controlled by [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) which is designed to keep an environment working -- so it automatically replaces machine that die using [auto scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/) (iirc).  Indirectly, the service did have your permission to do this, if you launched a beanstalk environment.

Comment: Ok, but I understand it that during registration I let checked that I want Elastic Beanstalk instance ? But why it created new separate instance at Ohio when I wanted just Frankfurt instance... why Elastic Beanstalk not created auto_scaling rules above instance at Frankfurt ?

Comment: Independent scaling groups (of one instance) exist in Ohio and Frankfurt. One may have been created by accident, its easy to not switch in the console, or use an API example for the wrong region.  Support can help you search through any events logged to show when this happened.